# Prototypejs conflicting with Underscore

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, underscore.js

EDIT:

I'm putting this at the top because ive finally figured out the actual problem.

Prototypejs is adding an Array.reduce function which is intefering with underscore (see: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/7)

There doesn't seem to be anything conclusive here other than "use prototype > 1.6.1) but I can't control what prototype is used unfortunately. Other than altering the _.reduce method to not use the native function or proxying any method that uses reduce (see comments) I can't see any nice way of fixing this issue.

---

I'm having an issue with Prototypejs being included on the same page as my javascript "app" where I am using underscore.

It seems that whenever I try and use the function _.unique it is actually calling the prototype function instead, this is inside a closure and I am using requirejs to load in _. When I change the order of the libraries included so my app is included before prototype then everything works fine, unfortunately I cannot use this as a solution as I will have no control of how this is included in any page.

I was wondering if anyone had come across this problem before and had a possible solution where _.unique will always call the underscore function rather than any global prototype function called unique.

Thanks

EDIT:

I actually think I might be wrong about the unique method being overridden actually. I have just added some console logs into the underscore function and it seems it is being called but its returning empty:

```
_.uniq = _.unique = function(array, isSorted, iterator) {
      console.log("called this");
      console.log(array);
    var initial = iterator ? _.map(array, iterator) : array;
    var results = [];
    // The `isSorted` flag is irrelevant if the array only contains two elements.
    if (array.length < 3) isSorted = true;
    _.reduce(initial, function (memo, value, index) {
        console.log("it never gets here");
      if (isSorted ? _.last(memo) !== value || !memo.length : !_.include(memo, value)) {
        memo.push(value);
        results.push(array[index]);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);
      console.log(results);
    return results;
  };
```

The first console log gives me "[1,2,3,1]" whereas the second gives me "[]". This does only seem to happen when prototype is included on the page though, so something is going on with it.

Ive added another log (it never gets here) which is ever executed. It looks like underscore is executing the "native" reduce method which is the one provided by Prototypejs which doesnt take an iterator.

Comment: Have you ever tried the `_.noConflict` [method](http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict)?

Comment: Whenever i try and use that I seem to get issues in other parts of my application.

Comment: @xiaowl Looks like its not something noConflict could deal with. In the _.reduce method it checks for a native reduce method and calls that if it exists. Seems that Prorotype is providing one (http://prototypejs.org/api/array/reduce) so this is being called but then the iterator is not being used ("it never gets here") so the result array isnt being filled. I don't know how I can get around this without editing the library.

Comment: How about set `Arry.prototype.reduce` to `null` before your method call? `val reduce = Array.prototype.reduce; call your method; Array.prototype.reduce = reduce`

Comment: @xiaowl okay, that does work. But the method is used all over the place seems like not a great way to solve the issue having to set to null and then reset this every time. Ill create a proxy method for now that does this but it does seem a bit messy, thanks for the quick solution though!

Comment: @xiaowl if you post this as an answer ill accept it as it has solved my problem and it seems like its the best way to do it in terms of keeping hold of prototype for the page and stopping it interfering with my app.

Comment: @xiaowl im not sure this solution is viable after more investigation, i will also have to do the same for _.union and _.intersection. There may even be more methods in there that need the same treatment that I just haven't come across.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Prototype.js overrides `reduce`, that's really a bad idea. If `reduce` is the only thing that Prototype.js messed, so how about set `Array.prototype.reduce` to `null` just at the start of `_.uniq`? Seems that `_.intersection` and `_.union` both rely on `_.uniq`.

```
 _.uniq = _.unique = function(array, isSorted, iterator) {
     var keepIt = Array.prototype.reduce;
     Array.prototype.reduce = null;
     //....
     Array.prototype.reduce = keepIt;
 };
```

Comment: it does seem that editing the underscore library is the lesser of two evils here. I've gone and edited the _.reduce function and just commented out lines 114-117 (where its checking for the native function). Do you think doing this in _.uniq would be a better solution, i don't know how many other functions use _.reduce.

Comment: Undersocre prefers to use the native `reduce` method for better performance. So removing the check of native function is not so bad ;D